# Can someone help me understand sequential files?

Tags: filesystems, database

Can someone help me understand:

1. What sequential files are?
2. How to create, access and add sequential files?
3. Which software can be used for these purposes?

I am a beginner in this area. I need your assistance, please.

Answer (score 1):

In general, database files are described as either [*sequential access*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISAM) (also called fixed-field-length or ISAM files) or [*random access*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_access).

With sequential access, a specific size is set for each field. For example, you might have a table in which you allocate 50 bytes (ANSI characters) for *Full_Name*, 80 bytes for *Street_Address* and 18 bytes for *Phone_Number*, with no other field, separator or end marker. Each row would be 50+80+18 = 148 bytes long. The first name starts on byte 00, the second name on byte 100 (base 10), the first phone number on byte 130 and so forth. In most cases, such a table is sparsely occupied, with most characters 00 (null), unless there are lot of long names, addresses and phone numbers.

Sequential tables are very easy to set up and to index, mathematically, without need for pointers or special characters (other than null), but are inefficient in use of storage space, and virtually unusable with multibyte characters.